# slideToggle() зациклился

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Проблема в том, что при следующем коде:

```
$('.menu ul li:eq(6)').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

при функции `hover` `slideToggle` работает некорректно, поскольку если очень быстро сто раз навести и увести указатель мыши, то потом надо будет пол минуты ждать, когда эти действия сто раз воспроизведутся. Мне надо, чтобы при наведении `slideToggle` срабатывала только 1 раз.

Answer (score -1):

Анимация завершается, когда убираешь мышку.

```js
$('.menu').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop(false, false).slideToggle(300);
});
```

```css
.menu {
  width: 200PX;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
</div>
```

Comment: Вы считаете такие скачки приемлемым вариантом для анимации?

Comment: Яуже решил проблему, тот вариант что автор дал действительно не совсем приемлем

Comment: Так что вопрос закрыт

Comment: Исправил скачки

Comment: @Nikita уверены?

Comment: @LiEm поделитесь решением

Comment: @Cheg да, уверен